# Should I call constructor method on the prototype or on a newly created instance?

Tags: javascript

I create a class `var Emp = function() { };` and then define functions in prototype of the class as

```
Emp.prototype.function1 = function() { /* some definition */ };
Emp.prototype.function2 = function() { /* some definition */ };
// .. so on
```

What would be impact on performance and which approach is effective and why?

Case 1:  if I call function

```
Emp.prototype.function1();
```

Case 2: if I first create an `Emp` instance

```
var empobj = new Emp();
empobj.function1(); // function calling
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Why create functions as properties of the prototype if you're not going to create instances? Case 1 is pointless. Case 2 is also pointless if the functions don't actually operate on the instances on which they're called.

Comment: Case 2 is the way to go

Comment: Yup that i know .. but dont know the exact reason ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the case 1, then the `this` context will point to the `prototype` object by default, hence the `instance` values cannot be accessed by using that.

For example:

```
var x = function(){ this.a = 10 };
x.prototype.y = function(){ console.log(this.a) };
x.prototype.y(); // This will print undefined since 
 //there is no properties other than y in the prototype of x.
```

At the same time in case 2, You can access the `prototype` object as well as the `instances` values. A sample code for that would be,

```
var x = function(){ this.a = 10 };
x.prototype.y = function(){ console.log(this.a) };
var obj = new x();
obj.y(); // `y` can be accessed also. And it will output 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the methods aren't called on instances, they should be static, i.e. be defined in `Emp` instead of in `Emp.prototype`:

```
function Emp() { /* ... */ }
Emp.function1 = function() { /* ... */ };
```

Or with ES6 classes:

```
class Emp {
  static function1() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
Emp.function1(/* arguments */);
```